# When using the Toolbox in Visual Studio 2010 to pull data from a MySQL server, keeps giving errors

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net

In my table called "test01" I keep getting an error when I run the site.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '[test01]' at line 1
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[test01]' at
>   line 1

From what I can see it is because the code that it is generating when I bring toolbox items and drop them in design view is this:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [test01]" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [test01] WHERE [test_id] = ?" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [test01] ([test_id], [TestName], [TestDescription]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [test01] SET [TestName] = ?, [TestDescription] = ? WHERE [test_id] = ?">
```

When I remove the [ ] brackets it works fine. Is there something I can do to change the functionality of this?

I hope this question makes sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brackets are a MSSQL way of qualifying stuff. You want backticks for MySQL.

```
SELECT * FROM `test01`
```

Comment: Is there a way I can have Visual Studio change brackets to backticks?

Comment: @DavidEllinger - how is your data source configured?

Comment: Ah, thank you! This allowed me to look at the configuration. I figured it out, I was trying to manually set it but if I just have it automatically do Insert it will be correct!